# getElementsByTagName('TBODY') failes in Chrome

Tags: dom, google-chrome

Given the element of a table found with `getElementById()`, I need to get the body element and add a row to it. This fails in Chrome:

```
var tabBody = expressionTable.getElementsByTagName('TBODY')[0];
```

but works in IE.

How can I get the body in all browsers (ie 8, Chrome, FF, and Safari)?

The code looks like this:

```
var expressionTable = document.getElementById(tableID);
var tabBody = expressionTable.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var expressionRow = createExpressionRow(FieldTagsValue, row);
tabBody.appendChild(expressionRow);
```

> tabody is 'undefined'

I think it might be because the table starts empty, and Chrome does not have a `tbody` element for an empty table. Could that be it?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't rely on anything working in IE - it might behave slightly non-standard.
i would also advise not expecting tags You have not declared in Your HTML to be present in DOM.

i would try going with an explicit tbody tag if You do rely on it being present in DOM :

```
<table>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

I know jQuery has some workarounds for handling tables (in IE) - so, unless You're patient to find out all the hacks Yourself, I would go with a library such as jQuery and add table elements like this :

```
$('#' + tableID).append(expressionRow);
```

Comment: Thats what it was, its not present in Chrome. I did this but I like your solution too

if (tabBody == undefined) { var tabBody = document.createElement("TBODY"); expressionTable.appendChild(tabBody); }

Comment: @BrianK right well as i said it all depends on how patient You're gonna be with making sure Your DOM code works correctly in all browsers ... :)